# SSRS : How to get multi values from two tables in same column

Tags: reporting-services, crm, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-2016

I got 3 datasets in my SSRS project they're :-

1. Visit
2. ExtraDeductionDS
3. CheckListDS

I have table in DB (Database) called "Visit" it's 1:many relation with "ExtraDeduction" & "CheckLists" tables.

First dataset bring the "VisitID" and "Name" with all related record in Extradeduction table.

[image]

And the second dataset bring the "VisitID" and "Name" with all related record in Checklist table.

[image]

Note : each of these two tables "Extradeduction, Checklist" has a column called "Name".

My question is : how to retrieve "Name" column in "Extradeduction & Checklist" tables that related in one visit and put the value in one column in my report, that's mean in the final result I need it to show like that :-

[image]

(102, 107) are visit ID column (int data type), and "Extra{Num} & Checklist{num}" they are the "Name" column (nvarchar Data type) .

Be informed that i'm using "Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch" connection type in my datasource, because my MS CRM is online so I don't have direct access to the database.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793738/joining-two-datasets-to-create-a-single-tablix-in-report-builder-3

Comment: Mr. BIDeveloper, that's not what i'm looking for, my case is : I have Visit table related 1:many with Extradeduction & Checklist tables, I need view all data in Extradeduction & Checklist tables that related with the visit, like what I explained in the post. The URL talk about LOOKUP function it's 1:1 relationship with two datasets, but I have 2 datasets 1:many relationship . Thanks ...

Comment: The link shows you how to join two datasets, that is all you need to do.

Comment: Mr. BIDeveloper, I have column called "Name" in these two tables "Extradeduction & Checklist". I need the result shows in one column, how to do that with the LOOKUP function.? I mean all the "Name" data in Extradeduction & Checklist tables shows under one column in the report .

Comment: How are you populating your datasets?  Are you using SQL queries?

Comment: Mr.  iamdave, No i'm using FetchXML, it's little bit harder than SQL and got some limitation, For example I can't use (union). https://s31.postimg.org/bgfdssw9n/XML.jpg  (Image) .

Comment: Any help please .?

Comment: I did it by adding new row and use LOOKUP function to make the data related with other dataset, but it just retrieves one record (First Record) in the second dataset.!! I think the problem in the grouping, how can I do it.? , any idea/help.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the lookupset function too ( [Description on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx))

And the multi lookup ( [Description on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210450.aspx))

The lookupset function seems to be the one you need.

Comment: Mr. Anne BRUNAS CASSININ, thanks for your answer, I tried to use Lookupset inside join function and it worked, but all related data became in one row, but what I need is put each related data in different rows. How to do that.?

Comment: I found this solution =join(lookupset(Fields!VisitID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ReferenceNo.Value, "VisitExtraDeduction"), VbCrlf). "VbCrlf" function to organize the data as multi rows, but actually it's still putting the related data in one row. Any other idea.?

Comment: Any one can help.?

Comment: I still can't retrieve the record in multi rows. Any help please.?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how todo it in an other way than yours. In other cases when I need lines in a cell i take a tablix in the cell, but I don't think it will work with a lookup.

Comment: Mr. Anne BRUNAS CASSININ, thanks a lot for your answer. I will try to find another way to do it. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try using Lookup instead of Lookupset without using join, like this:

```
=lookup(Fields!VisitID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ReferenceNo.Value, "VisitExtraDeduction")
```

If that not work, you can create a subreport and insert it on the column of main report where you want to display data. You have to pass respective ID from main report to subreport to fetch the desired data.