# SSRS 2012 merge datasets with grouping

Tags: reporting-services, reporting-services-2012

Dataset 1 = reportable data

[image: Reportable Data]

Dataset 2 = lookup info

[image: Lookup Info]

I am able to use Lookup for in order to "merge" their data into one table. (from here: [Joining two datasets to create a single tablix in report builder 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793738/joining-two-datasets-to-create-a-single-tablix-in-report-builder-3)). With the tablix pointed at Dataset1, the formula to get Location is:

=Lookup(Fields!PersonId.Value, Fields!PersonId.Value, Fields!Location.Value, "Dataset2")

[image: Can Get This Table]

My problem comes from trying to take that one step further and applying a Row Group that relies on the data found from Dataset 2.

[image: Want to Get This Table]

I am unable to re-design and somehow come up with a combined T-SQL query. Dataset 1 is sourced from an SSAS MDX expression that is greater than 8,000 characters, and thus trying to manipulate that into SQL through OpenQuery fails because the command length is too large.

I am also unable to flip around the datasets and have Dataset 2 be the driver for the report layout and do lookups on Dataset 1. Dataset 2 will not have context to the list of PersonId's from Dataset 1 and thus has many more rows than would be necessary. The lookup must come from Dataset 1.

Thank you for your time and advice!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is no problem at all when applying grouping via Lookup on Dataset 2. My issue was user error; I forgot to add ".Value" to the first field.

Bad: =Lookup(Fields!PersonId, Fields!PersonId.Value, Fields!Location.Value, "Dataset2")